# C# Serial Port exception

Tags: c#, serial-port

So I'm trying to get an specific device from a given portName and given baudRate. Whenever I create a new serialPort object, when I do `serialPortObject.Open()`, it throws the next exception, of type `System.IO.Exception`:

"An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist"

Code:

```
var serialPort = new SerialPort(portName, baudRate)
{
    RtsEnable = true,
    DtrEnable = true,
    ReadTimeout = 1000,
    WriteTimeout = 1000,
    DataBits = 8,
};
serialPort.Open();
```

Does anyone know this issue or how to fix it?

Comment: You've given the exception message, but what's the *type* of the exception?

Comment: System.IO.Exception (I guess thrown by System.IO.Ports), sorry.

Comment: Try to run the same code on a different machine and check. This appears to be more of system (driver or some thing else) problem rather than C# code problem.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ It makes it easier to find the line which threw that exception. Since it's an IOException, [this is probably the line](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/io/ports/InternalResources.cs,130)

Comment: What are the values of portName and baudrate? An IO Exception may happen if the Serial port is not happy with those settings. You can use a serial port monitor for further Investigation.

Comment: PortName -> "COM8", BaudRate -> 9600
Which is actually the portName where i have the device connected

Comment: Probably a problem with your system, not somethig related to programming; see e.g. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/dd05eca6-0f10-4b43-a860-6846cea310e7/error-an-attempt-was-made-to-reference-a-token-that-does-not-exist?forum=winserverManagement

Comment: I tried it in other machine and getting same exception.

Comment: Maybe I need to "clear" all ports before creating the serialPort?

Comment: You must also specify the Stopbits, Parity and Handshake properties.  Not that this is very likely to solve the exception.  If you can't get a better device driver for the device then be sure to take it out to the parking lot and run it over with your car several times.

Comment: Still having same exception including those properties...